# Declaring 2D arrays for strings vs integers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, character-arrays

Why is it that when I declare a 2D array for strings I need to use '*'

```
char *month[12][10] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
"May", "June", "July", "August",
"September", "October", "November",
"December"};
```

but when I declare it for integers, there's no need?

```
int numbers[2][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Comment: BTW, `month` can be written in this way: `char *month[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause in C „strings” *are represented* or *dealt with by pointers to its first character instead*.

Or telling it the other way — there's no string type in C language, only pointers to characters are there. *By convention* lot of libraries consider pointer to character as begining of a „string”, terminated with `0x00` byte or accept „string” length as a parameter, but there's no string type.

> when I declare it for integers, there's no need?

Cause integers are represented by themselves, not by theirs first byte address. When you use "something in quotes notation" it effectively gives your pointer to its first character and a pointer to character is noted as `char *ptr` in C.

When you see:

`char *str = "some string";`

it means variable `str` gets address of character `s`. And variable `str` is declared to point to a *character*, so it's `char *`. It's only a convention of some of libraries that using first letter of character you deal with string it begins with.

Comment: why doesn't the integer array need it? aren't all arrays pointers to their first element? Also my textbook doesn't use the * when they declare 2d string arrays, is it outdated?

Comment: Cause integers are represented by themselves, not by theirs first byte address. When you use "something in quotes notation" it gives your pointer to its first character and a pointer to character is noted as `char *ptr` in C.